# Hide 'Publish' Button From non Admins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, cancan

Am trying to hide this publish 'tick-box' from non-admin users. I used the CanCan plug-in and set up the correct permissions but am struggling with the code syntax. I have used **<%= if can? :publish, article %>** in the views/articles/_form.html.erb partial but it doesn't work?

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_names, "Tags" %>  <br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>  
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= check_box("article", "published" ) %>
    **<%= if can? :publish, @article %>**
<%= "Publish article" %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `<%`, not `<%=`. Also, the `if` statement is in the wrong place, and there's no closing `end` statement. Here's correct code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_names, "Tags" %>  <br />
    <%= f.text_field :tag_names %>  
</div>
<% if can? :publish, @article %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= check_box("article", "published" ) %>
    <%= "Publish article" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Comment: the code was missing '@' in the '@articles' too, its now working perfectly. Have updated my initial question if you can add to your answer too